# Dissasembling msdos 6.22, stack override prefix

Tags: operating-system, decode, disassembly

Edit: Ok, I found what I was looking for. My bad. I had some errors in my injected code. Now all register values are correct. :)

--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--

This is my first post. :) I want to learn assembly language and I wrote few programs so far. Curently I'm trying to disassemble msdos and see how this system was built and how things work under the hood. :)

I figured out mbr and now I'm at second sector of code. Which starts like this:

```
    eb 3c               jmp +59
    90                  nop
    
    fa                  cli
    33 c0               xor ax,ax   

    8e d0               mov ss,ax   
    bc 00 7c            mov sp,7c00 
    16                  push ss
    07                  pop es  
    bb 78 00            mov bx, 0078    
*   36                  // ss overide
*   c5 37               lds si,[bx] 
    1e                  push ds
    56                  push si
    16                  push ss
    53                  push bx
    bf 3e 7c            mov di, 7c3e    
    b9 0b 00            mov cx, 000b
    fc                  cld
    f3 a4               rep movsb
            ...
```

I have problem with lines marked as *. It's stack segment override. I removed bytes after * and insert my code which simply shows what is inside registers bx, ds, si.

First I checked what is [bx], DS:0 BX:0078

78 -> c7

79 -> ef

7a -> 00

7b -> f0

So this should be loaded into ds and si, right? But when I check ds and si values are diffrent:

ds: 00 0e

si: c7 0e

And finally when I use code with 36h it shows exactly same thing, nothing changes.

Maybe someone know what is going on and how to decode this? Thank You. :)